# JavaScript Scope in ES6 transpiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ecmascript-6

While working on a project where I had defined a class inside of an iife I had accidentally created a self var inside of the constructor. I ran into a problem when I moved some code out of a $http.get callback and into a function. The self var was not the same scope anymore. It would seem to me that the constructors scope would be the same as the classes scope but that is not the case. Is this just a side effect of transpiling or the way ES6 is meant to work?

Some code for clarity

```
(function () {
  class ServerManagementController {
    constructor($http, $scope, socket, Auth) {
      var self = this;
      this.$http = $http;
      this.$scope = $scope;
      ...
      $http.get('/api/servers').then(response => {
         //...code using self var - it became to long so I moved it out
         // into a function which broke the code and was fixed by moving
         // the var self outside of the constructor
         ...
```

On a side note any books on ES6 you would recommend?

Comment: I doubt that any problem you encountered was specific to ES6. ES6 didn't change how scope works (except maybe that we have block scope now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` binds the variable to the scope of the function so your  `var self` is bound to the function `constructor`,  the `class`  is just a *wrapper*  grouping multiple functions together into a class, but does not define itself a scope for the variables.

As of that you can't access `self` outside of the `constructor` function.

```
class ServerManagementController {
  constructor($http, $scope, socket, Auth) {
    var self = this;
  }

  anotherFunction() {
  }
}
```

Is the *same* as if you would write:

```
function ServerManagementController($http, $scope, socket, Auth) {
  var self = this;
}

ServerManagementController.prototype.anotherFunction = function() {
}
```

In both case `self` would be not available in `anotherFunction`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, however the self var was available but it was not the same self. It had a copy of everything but when updated it did not reflect in the original self scope. I'm thinking that perhaps the self var was captured in a closure. Thanks for the info/answer.

Comment: @MichaelHobbs maybe you or another library set `self` without defining it with `var` before and it was set in the global scope because of that.